# python flask Jinja2 implement parameters inside a MACRO

Tags: python, html, flask, macros, placeholder

Following [this guide](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#import), I want to implement my BACKEND parameters inside a macro.

For example:
My macro, called `infrastructure/buttons_utils.html`:

```
{% macro navigation_button_test(btn_name, placeholder) -%}
    <input  type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            value="{{ placeholder }}"
            id="{{ btn_name }} ">
{%- endmacro %}
```

And i render a HTML template with a list called `top_buttons_list` which is a list of dictionaries. My code is:

```
{% import 'infrastructure/buttons_utils.html' as buttons_utils %}

        <div class="vmiddle_wrapper">
            {% for button in top_buttons_list %}
                {% set button_params = button.button_params %}
                    <div> PLACEHOLDER TEST: {{ button_params.placeholder }} </div>        
            <div> {{ buttons_utils.navigation_button_test(btn_name='name', placeholder="{{ button_params.placeholder }}" ) }} </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I except my screen to show a button with the correct PLACEHOLDER, but the button actually shows this string: `"{{ button_params.placeholder }}"`

This is the HTML i got:

[image]

Comment: I tried to remove the `'` around the navigation_button_test placeholder param like:
            <div> {{ buttons_utils.navigation_button_test(btn_name='name', placeholder="{{ button_params.placeholder }}" ) }} </div>


to

            <div> {{ buttons_utils.navigation_button_test(btn_name='name', placeholder={{ button_params.placeholder }} ) }} </div>

But i get an error: `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do the following (removing the inner brackets should solve this issue):

```
{{ buttons_utils.navigation_button_test(btn_name='name', placeholder=" button_params.placeholder" ) }}
```

Jinja automatically knows how to implement objects inside, that's why you should only use the opening brackets {{ and closing ones }}